# Simplifying $\sum_{k=0}^{24}\binom{100}{4k}.\binom{100}{4k+2}$

Tags: combinatorics, complex-analysis, combinations, binomial-coefficients

> **How to evaluate the following series:** $$\sum_{k=0}^{24}\binom{100}{4k}\binom{100}{4k+2}$$

**What I have tried :** Considering expansion of $\displaystyle (1+x)^n=
\binom{n}0+ \binom n1 x + \binom n2 x^2+\cdots$

By this I can get easily the result :

$$\sum_{k=0}^{100}\binom{100}{k}\binom{100}{100-k}=\binom{200}{100}$$

Which seems to be almost similar to $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{24}\binom{100}{4k}\binom{100}{98-4k}$.

I think what I should do next is substitute $i$ and $-i$ and add equations.

What I am not sure is which ones to add.
Any suggestion or other approaches? Much Appreciated.

Comment: put 1, -1, i ,-i  as they are the fourth roots of unity

Comment: Ya I figured that out as I said above but where do I put them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the sum $S$. Using the symmetry of Pascal's triangle, $S$ equals
$$\sum_{k=0}^{24}\binom{100}{4k}\binom{100}{98-4k}.$$
Putting $j=24-k$ gives
$$S=\sum_{k=0}^{24}\binom{100}{96-4k}\binom{100}{2k+2}.$$
Therefore
$$2S=\sum_{r=0}^{49}\binom{100}{2r}\binom{100}{98-2r}.$$
This is the $X^{98}$ coefficient of $F(X)^2$ where
$$F(X)=\sum_{r=0}^{50}\binom{100}{2r}X^{2r}=\frac{(1+X)^{100}+(1-X)^{100}}{2}.$$
Then
$$F(X)^2=\frac{(1+X)^{200}+2(1-X^2)^{100}+(1-X)^{200}}4.$$
I get
$$8S=\binom{200}{98}-2\binom{100}{49}+\binom{200}{98}$$
etc.

Comment: I don't understand what happened at the substitution. Would you be kind enough to edit answer by elaborating?

Comment: @AnandManeesh Sorry, which substitution are you talking about?

Comment: j=24-k and how s became 2s and why did you opt that substitution ?Is there any other way?

Comment: $j=24-k$ just reverses the order of summation. I suggest you write out a few terms to get a better idea of what's happening.